# Types of Web Applications

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-application, web

What are the different types of web applications in SharePoint?
What are the possible ways to create each of them?
Are there any common predefined PowerShell scripts for each of them or each one of them are way different?
Does these scripts differ from one environment to other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web application in SharePoint is like an IIS site, which you can access it via a url either Http or Https and also you can configure the different authentication method for each web application.

> A SharePoint 2013 web application is composed of an Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) web site that acts as a logical unit for
>   the site collections that you create. Before you can create a site
>   collection, you must first create a Web application. Each web
>   application is represented by a different IIS web site with a unique
>   or shared application pool. You can assign each web application a
>   unique domain name.

here is Sp hierarchy:

[image]

Each web application has multiple site collections, we have many template which we can use to create a site collection i.e team site, publising site, search center, project etc.

Read this one for more understanding: [link1](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/sharepoint-terminology-farm-web-application-site-collection-top-level-site/)  [Link 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/erica/2014/04/01/sharepoint-web-apps-versus-site-collections/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me to know more about a web application. Also, can you let me know if there are different types of web applications?